# How to create field with plus-sign [drupal]

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

For our drupal backend we search something like this

```
+ - - - - - - - - - - - +
| Title           [ADD] |
| Page                  |
| Weight                |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - +
```

The [add] is needed because we need to add more than one on a Member. 
Our structure is called members, and because we have members with more than one title but on different pages we have to add more.

Hopefully my question isn't to hard to understand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose :
- "member" is a content type
- "title" is the title of the node

In that case, add a new field to the content type as multiple and use it/them to store a member title. Maybe you could add a taxonomy vocabulary for titles.
You can set a node title programmatically just before saving the node by concatenating all the titles of a member.